# Cross-platform assembly ((x64 || x86) && (Microsoft x64 || SystemV))

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, cross-platform, abi

I'm attempting to write some code in order to learn more about assembly and things like JIT compilers. So far I've been able to come up with an XOR function that should, in theory, work on x86 or x64 machines in both Windows and Linux environments.

Assuming that I understood things correctly, the `[RE]AX` register is used to hold integer return values while `[RE]DX` is one of the available registers for passing integers between functions. I chose not to strictly follow the ABI and pass the first argument using `[RE]AX` since it saves a `MOV` instruction without affecting the result.

Is there a better (more elegant or efficient) way to emit cross-platform assembly or are there any mistakes that I've made while developing this?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TInput>
static auto Xor(TInput const highPart, TInput const lowPart) {
    constexpr bool is16Bit = (std::is_same<TInput, int16_t>::value || std::is_same<TInput, uint16_t>::value);
    constexpr bool is32Bit = (std::is_same<TInput, int32_t>::value || std::is_same<TInput, uint32_t>::value);
    static_assert(is16Bit || is32Bit, "type must be a member of the type family: [u]int{16, 32}_t");

    if constexpr (is16Bit) {
        uint16_t result;

        #if (defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__) || defined(_WIN32))
            asm volatile ("xorw %%dx, %%ax;" : "=a" (result) : "a" (highPart), "d" (lowPart));
        #else
            #error "Unsupported platform detected."
        #endif

        return result;
    }
    else if constexpr (is32Bit) {
        uint32_t result;

        #if (defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__) || defined(_WIN32))
            asm volatile ("xorl %%edx, %%eax;" : "=a" (result) : "a" (highPart), "d" (lowPart));
        #else
            #error "Unsupported platform detected."
        #endif

        return result;
    }
}

#define HIGH_PART 4;
#define LOW_PART 8;

int main() {
    int16_t const a = HIGH_PART;
    int16_t const b = LOW_PART;
    int16_t const c = Xor(a, b);

    uint32_t const x = HIGH_PART;
    uint32_t const y = LOW_PART;
    uint32_t const z = Xor(x, y);

    std::cout << c << "\n";
    std::cout << z << "\n";
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Below is an example of how things might be improved; by "hoisting" the `result` variable and `if defined(...)` checks above the `constexpr` checks we can make things more generic.

```
template<typename T>
static auto Xor(T const highPart, T const lowPart) {
    constexpr bool is16Bit = (std::is_same<T, int16_t>::value || std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value);
    constexpr bool is32Bit = (std::is_same<T, int32_t>::value || std::is_same<T, uint32_t>::value);
    static_assert(is16Bit || is32Bit, "type must be a member of the type family: [u]int{16, 32}_t");

    #if !(defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__) || defined(_WIN32))
        #error "Unsupported platform detected."
    #endif

    T result;

    if constexpr (is16Bit) {
        asm volatile ("xorw %%dx, %%ax;" : "=a" (result) : "a" (highPart), "d" (lowPart));
    }
    else if constexpr (is32Bit) {
        asm volatile ("xorl %%edx, %%eax;" : "=a" (result) : "a" (highPart), "d" (lowPart));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `int16_t c = a^b;` and gcc that for target platform. I mean I'm not sure what you are asking: a) in raw machine code dealing with arithmetic there is no difference between win/linux, that's in ABI and service calls (irrelevant here) b) it's not clear where 64b steps into this and how, so far no usage in Q. c) the `xorw` is encoded differently depending on current CPU mode (16b mode vs 32b/64b mode), and I don't think there's sane way to cater for both... similar problems will arise while trying to cater for both 32 and 64 target platform, so what is your *target*?

Comment: @Ped7g There isn't a difference to the machine which registers are used but if I want my generated programs to "play nice with others" then I should adhere to the ABI of a target platform, no? The goal here is to eventually emit machine code, not compile an XOR expression using GCC. My potential targets are listed in the title: x64, x86, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: And emitting C and compiling that will lead to better (performance wise) machine code and larger cross-platform effect, as C compilers have many more targets, not just x86. While your approach doesn't gain any advantage over them. So I basically don't understand what precisely you are trying to achieve, and why by this way. (it is certainly educational and fun way, so if that is the motivation, go ahead, I just don't see any obvious (and low/medium effort) way how to get this to a state where it will have some real world benefit over using already available compilers).

Comment: @Ped7g I'm achieving knowledge and understanding, as stated in the very first sentence; not trying to beat modern compilers (yet!), just want to experience all the different complexities they deal with.

Comment: ok, I think it starts to make some sense to me, but I somehow unable to grasp it better... what do you mean by 32/64 and cross-platform precisely? So far you are showing C++ compile time generic/template programming ending by picking correct variant of your predefined assembly, i.e. you are not writing cross-platform assembly, you are writing N-variants of assembly per N platforms (which is normal, as assembly is notoriously stubborn to refuse to play nicely with "porting", there were many tries like goasm(?), llvm, etc. And they are great up to some point, but in extremes they're suboptimal)

Comment: @Ped7g Ah ok, my particular choice might've been terrible there; I meant cross platform in the OS sense. Pretty sure there is no getting around the N-variant problem due to the fact that we have to translate to a specific machine at some point.

Comment: Why do you care about Windows or Linux for your assembly code? You should care about ABI instead.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about those if 16b else if 32b ... why not to simply define two functions with appropriate argument types and let compiler pick the correct one based on the types used ... and in modern x86 world it makes often more sense (from performance point of view) to do `xorl` even with 16b values, depending what is their source and how you read them into registers and how the calculation continues after the `xor` ... but in modern x86 the whole concept of compiling per single operation makes little sense, that will bring interpreter-grade performance of total solution.

Comment: @SergeyA You're right, I really only care that the code is valid for the SystemV and Microsoft x64 ABIs.

Comment: I think you should pick real problems first, and try to create multiple variants of solutions, because at this moment this Q feels to me, like you are trying to solve some kind of artificial problem with some kind of artificial solution, which is normally resolved by simple one-liner in C++. And if assembly is of your interest, you can always check resulting machine code after compilation of that one liner. Of course if you want to understand how the compiler comes with particular solution, that may be a looong trip through multiple heavy books and thousands of lines of code...

Comment: @Ped7g Yeah, it **has** been a long trip; over a decade to be exact. If my goal was simply to XOR two values efficiently then I wouldn't be asking this question; the example is purposefully simple so that we can all focus on the important parts (the multiple ABI and register size "problems"). Now kindly stop poo pooing the merits of my question and answer it, or move on.

Comment: About ABI. You correctly (I think) let know compiler which registers you use, so the compiler will encapsulate those `xor` instructions with few more instructions safely sailing through that `xor` instruction. As long as you keep defining those constraints correctly, it should be safe. It will also force the optimizer to produce a bit of extra code (compared to plain C++ rewrite, where the compiler would be in full control of allocated registers and tailor them to the particular target ABI) to deal with your enforced choice. So your code is "cross platform", but it's fixed by compiler, not you

Comment: sorry, I'm off from here, I don't get your question.. maybe somebody else will understand you better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the compiler pass a function arg in EAX/RAX in 64-bit mode.  In 32-bit mode, you can use the gcc "regparm" calling convention, like `__attribute__((regparm(3))) int my_func(int,int);` to pass args in EAX,ECX,EDX in that order.  (So the compiler will need a `mov` before inline asm that has a function arg in EAX).

Or you can declare your functions with `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` to always use the SysV ABI, even when compiling on Windows.  But that only works if all callers are compiled by GCC/clang/ICC, not MSVC.  And it's worse in 32-bit mode; the i386 System V calling convention is crap: passing all args on the stack, and only int64_t is returned in edx:eax, not 2-member 64-bit structs.

Calling a `sysv_abi` function would probably also a `ms_abi` function to save/restore all of xmm6..15, unless the sysv_abi function call could inline and optimize away.  So on balance that's probably a bad plan if the function didn't already make heavy use of XMM regs and save/restore most of them.

---

**Using fixed register input / output constraints is not generally useful unless you're using instructions with implicit registers (like a shift count in `cl` if you can't use BMI2 `shlx` / `shrx`).**

Let the compiler do register allocation by using `"r"` and `"+r"` constraints.  (Or `"=r"` and `"0"` matching constraints) so your function can inline efficiently, regardless of where values are.  Also use `"re"` for inputs that can be register or 32-bit immediate.  Or even `"rem"` for inputs that can also be memory.  But if you use an input repeatedly, it might be better to get the compiler to load it for you before the asm.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Hard-coding the register allocation partially defeats the purpose of using inline asm instead stand-alone asm functions that the compiler has to call instead of inlining.

Look at the compiler-generated asm for your code to see what surrounding code it generated, and how it filled in the template by choosing operands.

Also note that `"r"` picks 16-bit registers for 16-bit types, and 32-bit registers for 32-bit types, so all this type-sizing stuff is basically unnecessary.  (Although depending how your inputs were written, using 32-bit `xor` could be better than 16-bit xor, maybe avoiding partial-register stalls if something later reads the full 32 or 64-bit registers.  But if your input regs were written with 16-bit operand-size, then on P6-family CPUs a 32-bit xor would create a partial-register stall.)  You can override the size filled in for a `"xor %0"` template substitution with `"%k0"` for the 32-bit size, etc.  See [x86 Operand Modifiers in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers).

Comment: Have been testing in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/UdOIuH), using the same settings as my local machine, and it appears to generate exactly what I asked it to. Just curious how that works since your first sentence leads me to believe it shouldn't...

Comment: @Kittoes0124: I was talking about *function* args.  After inlining, you aren't using any function args, just compile-time constants for mov-immediate.  So all you're seeing is the effect of inline asm defeating constant propagation.  (Also note that you compiled with intel-syntax mode on Godbolt, so your asm is a mix of compiler-generated Intel syntax and your one line of AT&T.  That wouldn't assemble.)  Anyway, https://godbolt.org/z/YXo6ZW shows a test caller that passes its own function args to Xor().  And shows that removing `volatile` lets two Xor(a,b) calls CSE down to reuse one.

Comment: Ah, thank you; that clears things up immensely. Maybe a better question to ask would be "How can I defeat the compiler more completely?" My goal is to try and implement things like constant propagation once I've defeated it.

Comment: @Kittoes0124: With gcc, you can use `if(__builtin_constant_p(a))` to ask the compiler if your inputs are compile-time constants.  (And if so, use pure C to leave constant propagation to the compiler.)  There's basically no hope for doing that with asm, unless maybe you use asm `.if` macros to check if an operand is a number or a register-name, with a string-compare macro condition.  That just sounds really silly, though.